# unexpected change in variable after python function call

Tags: python, pass-by-reference

Consider the following small python snippet where I add '2' to the first column of a 3 x 3 matrix:

```py
import numpy as np

def changeValue(kernel):
    kernel[0,0]=kernel[0,0]+ 2 
    kernel[1,0]=kernel[1,0]+ 2 
    kernel[2,0]=kernel[2,0]+ 2 
    return kernel

myKernel = np.array((
 [0, -1, 0],
 [-1, 5, -1],
 [0, -1, 0]), dtype="int")
CVkernel=myKernel

print(CVkernel)
a=changeValue(myKernel)
print(a)
print(CVkernel)
```

I get the following output

```
[[ 0 -1  0]
 [-1  5 -1]
 [ 0 -1  0]]

[[ 2 -1  0]
 [ 1  5 -1]
 [ 2 -1  0]]

[[ 2 -1  0]
 [ 1  5 -1]
 [ 2 -1  0]]
```

The value of myKernel clobbers CVkernel. I think there is an unintentional call-by-reference (pass-by-reference?) going on but I am not sure why.

If I define the function slightly differently

```py
def changeValue2(kernel):
    kernel=kernel + 2 
    return kernel
```

Then CVkernel is left untouched

```
[[ 0 -1  0]
 [-1  5 -1]
 [ 0 -1  0]]

[[2 1 2]
 [1 7 1]
 [2 1 2]]

[[ 0 -1  0]
 [-1  5 -1]
 [ 0 -1  0]]
```

**What is going on here?** I tried printing out the address register of the variables with print(id(kernel)) and print(id(CVkernel)) and that does not shed any light.

**EDIT**
Even when I use a 'safe' function call, kernel=kernel + 2 , the id of myKernel and CVkernel are the same.

```
id of myKernel  139994865303344
myKernel 
[[ 0 -1  0]
 [-1  5 -1]
 [ 0 -1  0]]
id of CVKernel  139994865303344
CVKernel 
[[ 0 -1  0]
 [-1  5 -1]
 [ 0 -1  0]]

**call made to changeValue2**

id of myKernel  139994865303344
myKernel 
[[ 0 -1  0]
 [-1  5 -1]
 [ 0 -1  0]]
id of CVKernel  139994865303344
CVKernel 
[[ 0 -1  0]
 [-1  5 -1]
 [ 0 -1  0]]
output a 
[[2 1 2]
 [1 7 1]
 [2 1 2]]
```

Shouldn't the id of each variable be different if they are different instances?

Comment: This doesn't make a copy: `CVkernel=myKernel` it just points `CVkernel` to the same array as `myKernel`. The you pass a reference of `myKernel` to the function, it changes it, returns the reference, which you store in `a`. Now you have three references to the same data. You need to explicitly make a copy if that's what you want `CVkernel` to be.

Comment: thank you for your reply. That's what I thought but it did not clarify why kernel = kernel +2 is ok but explicit references to the elements of the kernel array are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it as below:

```
def changeValue2(kernel):
    kernel += 2 
    return kernel
```

It shows the result as below:

```
[[ 0 -1  0]
 [-1  5 -1]
 [ 0 -1  0]]
[[2 1 2]
 [1 7 1]
 [2 1 2]]
[[2 1 2]
 [1 7 1]
 [2 1 2]]
```

You know well that It's `a call by reference`, but, In case of `kernel = kernel + 2`, the left `kernel` becomes another instance. Simply, It is same as `newKernel = kernel + 2`.

So, I changed it to `kernel += 2`, and it modified original `kernel` instance.

Comment: Thank you. I marked yours as the answer but would appreciate some 'under the hood' explanation of why kernel = kernel +2 is ok but explicit references to the elements of the kernel array are not. In both cases I am referencing the kernel object and modifying it. To extend your explanation then, the statement , kernel[0,0]=kernel[0,0]+ 2 , does not create a new instance but kernel = kernel + 2 does. Altho Imanux gave a valuable reference link, he also did not clarify this point.

Comment: @aquagremlin  Actually, Instance is memory. Multiple variables can refer one memory. So, `kernel = kernel + 2` creates new memory and set memory id to `kernel` variable. But, `kernel[0][0]` is an element of kernel as `int` type. So, `kernel` does not need to be instatiated. And, `kernel[0][0]` could create new memory for `int` object, internally.

Answer (score 1):

> Reason

You should never directly modify the object **kernel**
 you passed to the function `changeValue2`.

please check this link 
[How arguments passed in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) to find out what really happened when you try to modify the param

> Solution:

1. just use `changeValue`
2. use the return value: `myKernel = changeValue2(myKernel)`
3. Just a copy of [yaho cho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8796240/yaho-cho)'s solusion, Thanks again :)

```
def changeValue2(kernel):
    kernel += 2 
    return kernel
```

Comment: I think OP knows to use the returned value by `a=changeValue(myKernel)`.

Comment: Thanks, if he need to modify `myKernel`, `kernel += 2` is the easiest way :)

Comment: thank imanux for that valuable link. However I think you missed my problem. I do NOT want to clobber CVkernel with myKernel. Hence the function, changeValue , as well as your solution, kernel+=2, are not good because they BOTH clobber CVkernel with myKernel.

Comment: for me, the solution is to explicitly define CVkernel the same way I defined myKernel in the beginning. my goal is to dynamically change the convolution kernel during image processing.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest :

```
    CVkernel=myKernel.copy()
```